# Combining the column headers of a parsed XLSX into a single array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code which parses a .XLSX spreadsheet:

```
 module Ccenter
  module Utils
    module ZendeskCustomFields
      class UpdateStatusGroup
        require 'rubyXL'
        attr_reader :workbook ,:worksheet, :data

        def initialize
          @workbook = RubyXL::Parser.parse('app/assets/files/statusgroups.xlsx')
        end


        def get_data
          worksheet = workbook[0]
          data = worksheet
          rows = worksheet.map {|row| row && row.cells.each { |cell| cell && cell.value != nil}}
          header_values = data[0][8].value
        end
```

I am trying to gather all the column headers into one single array, however I've only been able to isolate single header values at a time, I can't find the correct method to pull each of them into a new array due to the fact they live in separate cells. Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: You just remove the `[8]` (e.g. `header_values = data[0]`) to get the entire first row. [Docs](https://github.com/weshatheleopard/rubyXL#accessing-a-row-array-of-cells-)

Comment: @engineersmnky Great, thanks! It's perhaps obvious but then how would that work in order to grab the header values of the column, as they require 2 arguments [0][1] etc

Comment: Not sure I understand the question but maybe you are asking something like `header_values = data[0].map(&:value)`?